# as academic discussions go

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is the full context:

When Dharma Kumar visited Calcutta and came with me to Ranajitda’s addas, she expressed astonishment at the range of issues we managed to discuss in our evening gatherings. **Even now, I feel that as academic discussions go, it would be hard to match those in the small unassuming apartment in Panditiya Road in the mid 1950s.**

How do you paraphrase the marked sentence?
I know what "as sb/sth goes" means, but still the overall meaning of the sentence is confusing for me.
Would you help me to get the idea of the sentence?
Thank You.
the reference:
At 23, Amartya Sen finished the work for his PhD in one year and then set up an economics department

Comment: https://www.nationalheraldindia.com/india/ranajit-guha-gave-a-new-dimension-to-history-writing-through-subaltern-studies  Please ***link to your sources***

Comment: Anyway, what are addas (or what is an addas)  That word isn't in the dictionary except as the proper name of one of Muhammed's slaves.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one paraphrase

> Despite my experiences since the 1950’s, I cannot remember academic discussions as varied and stimulating as those in that unassuming ….

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you.